# Cauchy sequence in $W^{1,2}$ is Cauchy in $L^2$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to show that the space $W^{1,2}$ is an Hilbert space,
i found this answered question:
[Showing Sobolev space $W^{1,2}$ is a Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283465/showing-sobolev-space-w1-2-is-a-hilbert-space)

which offer a proof, but I'm having trouble with one of the basic steps: in order to claim that if $f_n$ is Cauchy in $W^{1,2}$ than $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$ , I need to show that $f_n$ is Cauchy in $L^2$ , correct?
How can I show that?

Thanks
Shahar

Comment: Well, $\lVert \bullet\rVert_{1,2}\ge \lVert \bullet\rVert_2$.

Comment: yes but to prove that $f_n$ is Cauchy in $L^2$ its not enough since I need $<f_n,f_m>_{L^2}<\epsilon$ , this is not the norm but a inner product, and since $<f_n,f_m>_{W^{1,2}}=<f_n,f_m>_{L^2}+<f'_n,f'_m>_{L^2}$ I need to bound $<f'_n,f'_m>_{L^2}$ so it will be true. no?

Comment: No. In an inner-product space, just like in normed spaces, you need $\lVert f_n-f_m\rVert<\varepsilon$, not $\langle f_n,f_m\rangle<\varepsilon$ (which is hardly ever true: when $f_n\to f$, you have that $\langle f_n,f_m\rangle\to \lVert f\rVert^2$).

Comment: Wow, you are right! I was so incredibly confused! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lVert f\rVert_{1,2}\ge \lVert f\rVert_2$, $$\limsup_{\min(n,m)\to \infty}\lVert f_n-f_m\rVert_{2}\le\limsup_{\min(n,m)\to \infty}\lVert f_n-f_m\rVert_{1,2}=0$$